# AH02429: response header name contains invalid characters

Tags: apache2.4

I am using Apache/2.4.25 (Ubuntu) and self sighed certificate for ssl.I am getting this error in error.log.

> [http:error] [pid 17439:tid 140353432684288] [client
> 106.51.133.147:21780] AH02429: Response header name 'Strict-Transport-Security ' contains invalid characters, aborting
> request
>
> ```
> ServerName mystaging.cloudapp.net 
> Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
> ```

Answer (score 3):

There's trailing space in the header name in your error message.

Either you didn't actually copy and paste your configuration, or the header is set with trailing whitespace via some other means.

Answer (score 0):

Header requires a trailing colon.

`Strict-Transport-Security:`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security